Can a man choose not to be with his wife in the afterlife?
Say a situation arises as a result of which a man might resent his wife - and it is a valid reason - for example she is abusive or neglectful.
He may stay with her in this life for sake of children but He may desire not being married to her in the afterlife.
Is there any source on whether this is possible?

A man will have multiple wives in the afterlife and any hatred will be removed from his heart, so the concern you mention feels irrelevant.

@UmH Well for example, a man or a woman will marry an abusive or neglectful spouse?

If they both enter paradise then one will no longer be abusive\neglectful and the other will no longer retain resentment for how they were treated in the past.

The basic principle is that a married couple will remain together in paradise. This is provided that they were both Muslims at the time of death since only a Muslim can enter paradise and every Muslim will eventually enter paradise:

جنات عدن يدخلونها ومن صلح من آبائهم وأزواجهم وذرياتهم والملائكة يدخلون عليهم من كل باب
Gardens of perpetual residence; they will enter them with whoever were righteous among their fathers, their spouses and their descendants. And the angels will enter upon them from every gate
— Quran 13:23


ادخلوا الجنة أنتم وأزواجكم تحبرون
Enter the Paradise, you and your spouses, showered with bliss.
— Quran 43:70

There is however an issue regarding the case of a widow who remarried.There is disagreement on which of her husbands she will be with. The following opinions exist on this matter:

She will be given a choice
She will be with the husband who had treated her better in this world
She will be with her last husband

The first two are based on a hadith that is record for example in  Mu'jam al-Kabir while the third is based on a hadith in Mu'jam al-Awsat and also corroborated by other reports. The last one is considered more authentic by some, while all three can be reconciled by saying that if all her husbands were equally good to her then she will get the last one and otherwise she will get a choice and will choose the one who treated her better.
It should be kept in mind that the state of a person paradise is going to be different than this world. The inhabitants of paradise are not going to have the shortcomings or resentment which they might have had in this life.

ونزعنا ما في صدورهم من غل
And We will have removed whatever is within their breasts of resentment
— Quran 7:43


لا يسمعون فيها لغوا ولا تأثيما
They will not hear therein ill speech or commission of sin -
— Quran 56:25


لا اختلاف بينهم ولا تباغض
They will neither have differences nor hatred amongst themselves
— Bukhari

So: If they both enter paradise then one will no longer be abusive\neglectful and the other will no longer harbor resentment for how they were treated in the past.
